Use oauth token in ASP.NET Core to connect with a google client (gmail)
I've created a service that will run in the background and receive callback events from Gmail on behalf of my users. Letting users authorize my application and the required scopes in ASP.NET Core is trivial. Creating a Google client and using it to configure everything is also easy.
But I can't figure out how to combine those two actions.
Many examples for ASP.NET Core use something like this:
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = GoogleOpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public async Task<IActionResult> Callback([FromServices] IGoogleAuthProvider auth)

But when I use that in combination with builder.AddAuthentication().AddGoogleOpenIdConnect(), it complains that the credentials are incorrect.

'UnderlyingCredential is not an OIDC token provider. Only ServiceAccountCredential, ComputeCredential, ImpersonatedCredential are supported OIDC token providers.'

I've also seen that I can get a SecurityToken from the OnTokenValidated callback, but how can I use that token to connect using the Google client?
 .AddGoogleOpenIdConnect(options =>
 {
     options.Events.OnTokenValidated = context =>
     {
         // Can I use this token in some way?
         Console.WriteLine(context.SecurityToken);
         return Task.CompletedTask;
     };

The client
//something from the ASP.NET core auth process
var cred = /* what should be here */;
var service = new GmailService(
       new BaseClientService.Initializer { HttpClientInitializer = cred });

I also would like a token with a longer lifetime, as my app will aid with some aspects of my user's email over a longer duration.

Are you  using Windows Authentication or OAUTH2?  OIDC is OAUTH2.  I think your credentials is Windows and you are trying to pass a Windows Authentication to OAUTH2.

oauth + cookies. Windows is turned off.

If you are using asp net sign-in in your app please note that if you use the official google .net client library it will Sign the user out as its using the same cookies.  This was a public service message not related to your issue at hand

here is the official sample

The error is indicating the token/cookie is not valid.  The cookie could be old (may be a windows cookies).  May be you need to delete the cookie.  No sure what you mean by oauth + cookie.

I mean that I use AddAuthentication().AddGoogleOpenIdConnect().AddCookie(). But on the controller, that gives the error I request that Google is used for authentication as I showed in my first code snippet.
